# How to export all raw data from Google Analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, report

Google is sunsetting Google Analytics support from [February, 2020](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112).

> After our service is fully turned down in February 2020, these legacy properties will no longer be accessible via the Google Analytics UI or API, and the **associated data will be deleted** from Google Analytics servers. In advance of this turndown, **we recommend that you export the data** so you can retrieve it later.

In their [learn more about exporting](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1038573) section they said,

> To export a report:
>
> Open the report you'd like to export. Analytics exports the report as it is currently displayed on your screen, so make sure that you've applied your desired date range and report settings.

But I see, in the **GA dashboard** report section, when I create reports, I am to add categories/filters etc. which I assume does not eventually reflect full analytics data in the report.

**How can I export full raw data from Google Analytics** so that I can import in Firebase when feature is available in future? I see options to export reports from GA dashboard but did not find any way to export full data.

**Is there any other recommended way to avoid data loss for GA?**

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to access raw unprocessed data of GA property

Comment: @ДмитроБулах how can I make a report that covers all data?

Comment: I didn't say you can

Comment: @ДмитроБулах I understood what you mentioned but they have way to export a report (unlike raw unprocessed data). But I was asking if I can ignore filtering and make a report covering all the data. Sorry for my bad language. Thanks.